# Twilio - Recognising a user has ended a call

Tags: twilio

I am a junior developer currently working on creating our own phone system with Twilio. At the moment when I initiate a call from the client and the customer picks it up at their end its all working well until the user hangups. The call is still remaining connected until I end the call from the browser.
How can I recognise that the user has ended the call from their end?

Comment: Do you have a handler for the disconnect event on the connection object? (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#disconnect)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a callback in the Twilio API called `"completed"`

> The call was answered and has **ended** normally.

*[Source](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#request-parameters-call-status)*

Comment: I've added a status callback url but again this is only triggered when i end the call from the browser not when the call has been hung up from the other end by the user

Answer (score 1):

Danielle, hello! I'm Megan from Twilio.

It sounds like your scenario is related to [making outgoing calls from the browser](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/client/outgoing-calls).

Have you followed the steps to [hang up calls in the browser](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/client/hangup)? Specifically:

Use `.disconnect()`:

```
/* Log a message when a call disconnects. */
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
    $("#log").text("Call ended");
});
```

followed by a `hangup()` function using `.disconnectAll()`:

```
/* A function to end a connection to Twilio. */
function hangup() {
    Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
}
```

Consider [tracking status from the client connection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#status). When it is `closed` you can invoke the above functions.

Also, it might help if you turn on debugging in Client via:

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token, {debug: true});
```

The Javascript console will show all the low level events received.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Megan,thanks for your help the debugging in Client is really useful! The above still hasn't solved the problem though. I can hang up the call from the browser fine that is all working. It is when the person at the other end hangs up on their phone the call still remains connected and none of the events are fired. It seems as though the call can only be ended from my side when im making the call from the browser which is not useful as if the customer at the other end, ends the call first we do not want to be having to hit the end call button in the browser again to ensure it is disconnected.

Comment: Hey Danielle, to Phil's point have you tried  `.disconnect( handler(connection) )? With that you can track the connection status (i.e. if conn.status = "closed") as I mentioned above and toggle that to disconnect the device. Hanging up in the docs is specifically tied to a button in the js. You need to invoke hangup upon your desired event.

Answer (score 0):

For this I finally resolved it by setting the hub connection back to null on the disconnect.

```
this.connection.disconnect(() => {
                    this.connection = null;
                });
```

Comment: hey @Daniellesmith31, i'm having the same problem, would you be able to share your code for this solution? it's unclear what `this` is referring to

Comment: Hello @Daniellesmith31, I'm having the same issue, can you just clarify your answer on where have you written the code and how are you recognizing that customer has ended the call?

Comment: Hi @karan-patokar, can you share your code if you have fixed this issue? Thx